# What is node in Selenium Webdriver GRID?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid2

From what I learn-

*Nodes are the Selenium instances that will execute the tests that you loaded on the hub.*

So this means, on a `node` which runs 5 browsers on a particular OS has basically 5 nodes to run.

please explain...

Answer (score 0):

You can consider nodes as a server on a particular os, that contains multiple browsers, like 5 chrome, 5 ff, 5 safari. All of those browsers (sessions) are in 1 node. This node will connect to another server called hub. You can connect them as many as you have.

In the picture there are 6 nodes. 2 of them contain multiple browsers as you see.

[image]